# Listview display drawables instead of integers

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-drawable

I'm trying to make a very simple listview of drawables. While I can find resources which address this http://stellarwavedev.com/2012/05/android-custom-arrayadapter-text-and-icon/ - I am still relatively unfamiliar with Android and find it somewhat difficult to parse these more complicated examples.

The code below correctly displays the ArrayList; albeit as integers (as it's asked to). However, any attempts I make to change the generics of ArrayAdapter causes eclipse to start complaining about type.

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fruitList);
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    values.add(R.drawable.apple);
    values.add(R.drawable.banana);
    values.add(R.drawable.cherry);
    values.add(R.drawable.date);


    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried and how did it fail, what was the error message?

Comment: are you using CustomAdapter???

Comment: @LajosArpad as described in the question, there wasn't any runtime or compile error as such; it just displayed numbers instead of images.

Comment: "causes eclipse to start complaining about type" I was wondering about what you have tried and what was the error message. I suppose it is Java who is complaining about the type, not Eclipse. So, anyway, I am interested to know more about this complaining about the type.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

to

```
 ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new MyCustomAdapter<Integer>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```